# Webcam works locally but not remotely

Tags: windows, laptop, webcam

I have a Lenovo Y50 running a fresh install of Windows 10, updated to the latest version.

My webcam works only locally. For example, the Camera app works, as does [this particular webcam test site](https://www.vidyard.com/cam-test/), which advertises the fact that it never sends any data *to* their servers. However, all other test sites, Skype, etc., which rely on you sending webcam data to them and them playing it back to you, don't work. The problem occurs in both Chrome and IE.

What could be the reason for this?

Edit: privacy settings are okay. This was the first thing I tried.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How to control which apps can use the camera
Go to Start, then select Settings > Privacy > Camera.
Choose your preferred setting for Allow apps to access your camera.
Under Choose which apps can access your camera, turn on or off the individual settings for apps and services.

Comment: This was the first thing I checked -- the privacy settings are set to 'allow'. Also tried restarting a couple times.

Comment: Facing the same issue, @knzhou , how did you resolved this issue ?

Comment: @MadhurYadav I didn't, I got a new computer.